# Updating all rows within a single column using phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Please could someone help me write an SQL statement which I can use to update a table in my MySQL database using `PHPMyAdmin`?

**Background**

I have a database called **XYZ** and a table called **v2rns_content**

The table has a number of columns including one called **images**

Each row in the images column has the same content, apart from the file path  which is different Ex:

```
{
   "image_intro":"images\/news_images\/Logos\/Logo.png",
   "float_intro":"",
   "image_intro_alt":"",
   "image_intro_caption":"",
   "image_fulltext":"",
   "float_fulltext":"",
   "image_fulltext_alt":"",
   "image_fulltext_caption":""
}
```

Where **images/news_images/Logos/Logo.png** is the file path.

I would like to update this file path by adding an additional level e.g.

**images/news_images/legacy/Logos/Logo.png**

**Question:**
Is it therefore possible to search my images column for the text **images/news_images** and replace this with **images/news_images/legacy** for all the rows within this column?

**Notes:**
It's worth noting that the v2rns_content table is proving difficult to export(due to size and special characters) otherwise I'd simply find and replace in excel then import it again using phpMyAdmin.

The v2rns_content table contains upwards of 20,000 records

I am not an expert in SQL so would appreciate it (if possible) if I'm able to achieve this using the SQL function in phpMyAdmin.

Thanks for your help in advance. It's much appreciated.

Comment: is `images` the only column you want to update?

Comment: Yes it is. I want everything else to remain the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a good perspective on your schema. In order for you to update all of the columns with the value (same or different, depending what you do with it in PHP).

This will replace the whole value:

```
UPDATE v2rns_content SET image_intro ='images\/news_images\/legacy' 
WHERE image_intro LIKE '%images\/news_images%'
```

If you want to replace part of the dir path you might want to do this:

```
UPDATE v2rns_content 
SET image_intro = REPLACE(image_intro , 'images\/news_images', 'images\/news_images\/legacy')
```

Here's an official ref page: [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace](http://Replace%20function)

Comment: If my existing content is
`{
   "image_intro":"images\/news_images\/Logos\/Logo.png",
   "float_intro":"",
   "image_intro_alt":"",
   "image_intro_caption":"",
   "image_fulltext":"",
   "float_fulltext":"",
   "image_fulltext_alt":"",
   "image_fulltext_caption":""
}`

Will this code change it to: `{
   "image_intro":"images\/news_images\/legacy\/\/Logos\/Logo.png",
   "float_intro":"",
   "image_intro_alt":"",
   "image_intro_caption":"",
   "image_fulltext":"",
   "float_fulltext":"",
   "image_fulltext_alt":"",
   "image_fulltext_caption":""
}`

Comment: It really depends how you store it. I'm not sure how or if you escape it before you save it to your DB. In the case where you dont do anything and string stores like this `images\/news_images\/Logos\/Logo.png`, then replace `images/news_images` string with your stored data.

Comment: Based on your description, I figured that you only want to search for `images/news_images`.  % signs act as a wild card, it should find it even if there are other characters before and after.

If you not sure if it's going to work, you can even run this: `SELECT * FROM images WHERE images LIKE '%images/news_images%'` this will allow you to see the affected rows before you run the update query.

Comment: I've just given that a go and get an empty result set

Comment: If I understand your correctly, your code should search for the term `images\/news_images` in the text below and replace it with `images\/news_images\/news_images` Is this correct?

`{ "image_intro":"images\/news_images\/Logos\/Logo.png", "float_intro":"", "image_intro_alt":"", "image_intro_caption":"", "image_fulltext":"", "float_fulltext":"", "image_fulltext_alt":"", "image_fulltext_caption":"" }`

The content above is copied from the database so this is what is stored in each row of the image column.

Comment: Sorry the select method had a typo. Try this `SELECT * FROM v2rns_content WHERE images LIKE '%images/news_images%'`. I didnt know this is what you have in your DB already. Then see my answer above, I will edit it with correct string