# Find and Replace Using phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Please could someone help me understand why the following SQL doesn't work:

```
UPDATE `v2rns_content_new` 
   SET `images`= REPLACE(`images`, 'images\/news_images', 'images\/news_images\/legacy');
```

I am trying to find and replace the bold part of the following string (there are multiple records in the database with similar strings but the filenames e.g. example.png are different):

{"image_intro":"**images\ /news_images**\ /example.png","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}

Please note: I asked a related question yesterday (which will provide some background) but I feel that this question is best asked separately - [Updating all rows within a single column using phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080066/updating-all-rows-within-a-single-column-using-phpmyadmin/31080195)

Comment: I don't think you need to escape the `/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve the issue by changing the already escaped \ to \

e.g. `UPDATE v2rns_content_new SET images = REPLACE(images, 'images\\/news_images, 'images\\/news_images\/legacy')`

Thanks to @GeolezTrol for pointing me in the right direction.